# What is the best way to see if Dictionary string values contain some pattern and at the same time doesn't contain another in C#?

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, contains

Let's say I have a dictionary `Dictionary<string,sting>.`

I want to see if the string values of this dictionary contain some string pattern, let's say "abc" and at the same time doesn't contain patterns "def" and "ghi". Also, I want this check to be not case sensitive.

I can write it like this:

```
var options = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        ...     
if (!options.Any(kvp1 => (kvp1.Value.Contains("def", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
&& !options.Any(kvp2 => kvp2.Value.Contains("ghi", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
&& options.Any(kvp3 => kvp3.Value.Contains("abc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))                               ))
        {
        Do Something...
        }
```

So I wonder, is there more elegant way to perform such operation?

UPD: This code sure has a bug. What I desire is to check that values list has at least one element that contains "abc", and no elements at all that has "def" and "ghi". So edited code a bit.

Comment: use a few `||` operators instead of calling `.Any` multiple times.

Comment: @DanielA.White The current code checks each requirement independently, chaining them all inside a single `.Any(...)` would require the requirements to be true for the same item or it would mask one requirement because another hit for the same item.

Comment: You need to make sure your code is _correct_ before trying to make it more _elegant_.  Right now it does not look correct.  It will succeed if _any_ value does not contain `"def"` and _any_ value does not contain `"ghi"` and _any_ value contains `"abc"`. Do you need to apply those conditions to _each_ value?  Or should you be using `!options.Any(..)'` instead?

Comment: @DStanley  Basically yes, what I need to check is that there are no values that  has "def" and "ghi", and at least one with "abc", so I guess I have to go through each value, otherwise the check will stop as soon as it will find the first value that satisfies this condition. For example it will find line "abc" without "def" and "ghi" and wouldn't go to look for other lines only with "ghi" of "def'

Comment: OK So what is your objective of "more elegant" code?  Fewer lines?  Better performance?

Comment: @DStanley As my list is small I guess performance is not the main thing at this point, but the "fewer lines" and better readability is what I desire, because at this point as you rightly noticed I have already lost in my own code and made a bug.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var includedValues = new[] { "abc", "dfg" };
var excludedValues = new[] { "hij", "klm" };

var cultureInf = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var containsPredicate = new Func<string, string, bool>((s1, s2) => {
    return cultureInf.CompareInfo.IndexOf(s1, s2, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)>=0;
}); 

if (
includedValues.All(v => options.Values.Any(kv =>containsPredicate(kv, v)))
&&
excludedValues.All(v => !options.Values.Any(kv =>containsPredicate(kv, v))))
{
    // do smthg
}
```

Comment: Even shorter : `values.All(v => options.Values.Any(v.Contains))`

Comment: I edited my answer butt kept you advice actual, thank you.

Comment: How does this take into account the OP's statement of *I want this check to be not case sensitive.* ?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things to take care of. Culture-based case-insensitive comparison and dynamic, non hard-coded patterns for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
  internal static class Program
  {
    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var options = new Dictionary<string, string>();

      var compareCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
      var patternsNeeded = new[] { "abc", "def" };
      var patternsForbidden = new[] { "ghi", "xxx" };

      Func<KeyValuePair<string, string>, bool> meetsCriteria =
        kvp => patternsNeeded.Any(p => compareCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(kvp.Value, p, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0)
           && !patternsForbidden.Any(p => compareCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(kvp.Value, p, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0);

      var dictionaryContainsHits = options.Any(meetsCriteria);
    }
  }
}
```

If your dictionary is large, you may want to throw in an `.AsParallel()` here and there. As those are all read operations, it should work fine.

Not sure if you want `.Any()` or `.All()` for the patterns that are in your positive list. Take the one that fits your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access values via Values property on the dictionary object.

Well, you can create your own linq to do this approach:

```
public static class ExtendedLinq
{
    public static bool All<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params Func<T, bool>[] conditions)
    {
        foreach (var condition in conditions)
            if (!source.Any(condition))
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

and then usage:

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
if (options.Values.All((t => t.Contains("abc")), (t => !t.Contains("def")), (t => !t.Contains("ghi"))))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Hope its finally what you wanted.

Btw, that contains which is case insensitive is not part of the framework, so I didnt include it, since you already have it.

old (misunderstood the question):
    var options = new Dictionary();
    if(options.Values.Any(t => t.Contains("abc") && !t.Contains("def") && !t.Contains("ghi")))
    {
        // Do something
    }

It depends on the context, because it might be usefull to take a look on the [Sorted dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.

Comment: he wants to check if the dictionary contains item with value x, and y ,and z.

Comment: I dont understand what do you not like to be honest.

Comment: if you use && and try to evaluate all 3 conditions in a single any that would make the any() to search for a single record of the dictionary,if thats the aim of the OP then i would agree buti read in the comments that its looking for a dictionary that contains an item with x and without y and z.so thats different.

Comment: How does this take into account the OP's statement of *I want this check to be not case sensitive.* ?

Comment: Virgil: Well, my bad. I have edited my post. It should be finally what he wanted.

Comment: nvoigt: Case insensitive Contains method is not part of framework, so you have to write your own (extension) method for this kind of comparison. So in OP's context, you just dont use my contains, but his.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest that you do this :

```
 var dictionaryVal = d.Select(p => p.Value.ToLower());
 string string1 = "string1";
 string string2 = "string2";
 string string3 = "string3";

 if (dictionaryVal.Contains(string1.ToLower())&&dictionaryVal.Contains(string2.ToLower())&&dictionaryVal.Contains(string3.ToLower()))
 {
     //your code here
 }
```

that is to see if a dictionary's values contain string1 but does not contain string2 and string3.however...
if you like to check for a single dictionary item and check all 3 strings against the same item's value it would be :

```
if (d.Any(p => p.Value.Contains(string1.ToLower()) && !p.Value.Contains(string2.ToLower()) && !p.Value.Contains(string3.ToLower())))
{
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: How does this take into account the OP's statement of *I want this check to be not case sensitive.* ?

Comment: @nvoigt i somehow missed that part but i have edited the answer.thanks for pointing it out.